# Android remote Service start and stop

Tags: android, service

I'm developing an app that makes asynchronous calls to server for notifications. Everything works fine in the main activity. Now what's bothering me, that i need a service that would poll for notifications when the app is not active (just like GMail stock app). So I start remote service in another process in the main activities onStop function like that:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(prefs.getBoolean(OPTIONS_KEY_SERVICE, false)) {
        startServiceIntent = new Intent(CloudAlarmsService.MY_SERVICE);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("duidCodes", duidCodes);
        startServiceIntent.putExtras(b);
        Log.d("SSE_SERVICE", "Starting Service");
        startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

It works fine, i get notifications after the activity was closed. Now i would like to stop remote service on activity start (so i won't have activity and service polling server concurrently). I do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    stopService(new Intent(CloudAlarmsService.MY_SERVICE));
    Log.d("SSE_SERVICE", "Stopping service");
}
```

CloudAlarmsService.MY_SERVICE is a string in my service class:

```
public class CloudAlarmsService extends Service {
    public static String MY_SERVICE = "cloudindustries.alarms.service.BACKGROUND_SERVICE";
...
```

and also it is declared in manifest xml like that:

```
<service android:process=":alarms_poller" android:name=".CloudAlarmsService">
     <intent-filter android:label="@string/serviceStopService">
           <action android:name="cloudindustries.alarms.service.BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But service is not stopped and it keeps working. After i close the main activity another instance of service spawns and continues polling.

Is there something i am missing out?
Or maybe this is a bad use for a remote service or even there is another type of service / manager which could be used for such purpose?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:**

Question clarification: Is it possible to stop remote service from different activity (which did not start the service)?

Comment: what does onStartCommand returns ? STICKY ? (not sure you can stop a service from a different instance than the one starting it, though)

Comment: Nope not STICKY, I intend to return sticky when i will find a way to stop it for different instance.

Comment: are you sure it is stopped ?

Comment: why does it run in a separated process ?

Comment: If i start it in same process, the service is being killed by android when activity is destroyed. And it is not stopped, that's what i want to do.

Comment: @RokasJurevicius : have you try it to stop using Intent? and i think if you are using any thread or timer for polling data to server then use a flag to stop/start Thread/timer in service.

Comment: The intent which was used when starting service is destroyed after activity was stopped. So i can't have it. I am stopping all timers in service's onDestroy, but it doesn't get called

Comment: @RokasJurevicius : i means try to stop all timers before stoping service and try as to stop your service `Intent intent  = new Intent();intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), CloudAlarmsService.class); getApplicationContext().stopService(intent);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K : It seems your solution did the trick. Please post it as an answer and i will mark it as accepted

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK This would imply that the intent resolution mechanism works differently for `startService()` than for `stopService()`. I don't quite believe that. I guess I'll need to build my own test program to verify this. OP's code looks absolutely OK to me.

Comment: @DavidWasser : this is just matter of   Intent Action because Rokas Jurevicius is not sending right intent with action for stopping service.

Comment: @RokasJurevicius : plz see my edit i'm stopping service in your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to stop `CloudAlarmsService` service as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), CloudAlarmsService.class); 
getApplicationContext().stopService(intent);
```

Comment: I think first version is more concise and simple. Second function can bring a bit of confusion inside the code..

Comment: @RokasJurevicius : yes you are right but when we want to use action for starting/stopping an `Activity` , `Serivce` or any other application Component we will need to send fully qualified intent

Comment: If you specify the component explicitly (which you are doing in the first example with `CloudAlarmsService.class` and in the second example with `setComponent()` and `setClassName()` then there is **no Intent resolution** going on. You are bypassing the Intent resolution process (which is what happens when you just specify the ACTION, as OP is doing in his original calls to `startService()` and `stopService()`). What I'm trying to get at is that it **should be possible** to stop a service **without** explicitly setting the component. Of course, I may also be wrong about that.

Comment: Your comment about using **action for starting/stopping...** isn't correct. When OP starts the service, he is using some random string as the Intent ACTION and nothing else. **Intent resolution** happens, whereby Android tries to find a suitable `Service` component that has an `IntentFilter` that matches this ACTION. It finds one (his service) and starts it. The Intent ACTION field isn't used to specify "start" or "stop", that magic is done in the framework itself.

Comment: @DavidWasser : my both solution worked .i think this topic need some expert advice i will ask this question soon to SO

Comment: @DavidWasser : your are absolutely  right. same as i have also read in android docs but daily i have seen lots of question in which they are trying to start service / or Activity using Action but get failed

Comment: Usually there are explainable reasons why Intent Resolution isn't working. I've also seen these questions. If you look in the Android sample code that comes with the SDK, in /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.java you can see where they show starting and stopping a service using ONLY an ACTION string (just like OP is doing).

Comment: I realize that your solutions worked. That's actually not my point here. I see your solution as a workaround. What if I don't know the names of the components that I want to start and stop? In this case, I **could** use an ACTION to see if there are any components available that will do what I want. This is **supposed to work**, so I'd like to know why it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidWasser: this not true in case of service your point is only right in case of Activity.